# Why is adding new files to a new repo difficult?

Tags: git

When I create a new repo and then clone it and try to add a file then my system says that there is no repo. Why?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/montao/oslab.git
Cloning into 'oslab'...
Username for 'https://github.com': montao
Password for 'https://montao@github.com': 
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell$ ls
a.out     cpipe.c.orig  digenv.c.orig    omdirigering.c.orig  pipe.c.orig  types.c~
backup.c  digenv        digenv.dat       oslab                RunSafe      types.c.orig
cpipe.c   digenv.c      omdirigering.c   pipe.c               RunSafe.c
cpipe.c~  digenv.c~     omdirigering.c~  pipe.c~              types.c
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell$ git add digenv.c
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell$
```

Comment: are you sure you are in the correct subdirectory? After cloning there should be a subdirectory "oslab" where your git repo resides.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Ok there is one. I didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clone your repo to an `oslab` folder and you try to add your files in a different folder in your case `~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell` that looks not really correct. Go to the correct folder then you can add and commit your file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why git is stating, you are not inside your repository is because you need to cd into the directory that contains the repository. eg:

```
git clone https://github.com/montao/oslab.git
cd oslab
git add digest.c
```